# Android - Best way to use static variables / objects

Tags: android, static

In my android app, I initialise few variables and few objects in my Splash Activity and use those variables everywhere else..

Everything works fine but when app is in background and is restarted, static variables become null..

I have to apply a lot of null checks and re-initialisations to handle this.

Am i doing right ?

**Mainly, I have to retain a LinkedList.. So, what could be the best way to store that linked list.**

Comment: you can use preferences to keep such data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am i doing right?

No. Your description shows that you want to persist your data. So using static variables is really not an option for you for reasons you already mentioned. Look at options to persist data. There are several that each fit a scenario.

For example (there are more):

- Database
- Sharedpreferences (key/value store)
- Write to file

Read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I have to retain a LinkedList.. So, what could be the best way to store that linked list.

Comment: It depends. If this is the only data you have to store than it would probably be easiest to make it parcelable and store it in sharedpreferences. If you don't 100% understand what that means, there are many examples to be found on the net. It's not something I could answer here